# $V/(U \cap W)$ is finite dimensional iff $V/W$ and $V/U$ are finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Where obviously $U, W$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$. I have one direction, i.e. if $V/W$ and $V/U$ are finite dimensional, $V/(U\cap W)$ is finite dimensional using the isomorphism theorems. How can I get the other direction?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Show that $V/U$ is a quotient of $V/(U\cap W)$.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: By finding the right subspace of $V/U$ of course.

Comment: I've never heard that terminology, and a quick Google search doesn't seem to turn up a nice definition. Sorry to be bothersome but can you explain a little further?

Comment: @user115656 It just amounts to showing that there is a surjective linear map $V/(U\cap W)\to V/U$. Can you think of one?

Comment: Sure: $\phi(v+(U\cap W)) \rightarrow v+U$, right? I know I'd need to show that this is a well-defined linear map and is surjective, but that's the cannonical choice, right?

Comment: @user115656: I'm sorry, I went to bed shortly after posting the comment above. Which part of it you haven't seen before? Quotient?

Comment: Well, I had not seen "quotient" on its own before, although I know what a quotient space is. I had also not seen "right subspace" before.

Comment: @user115656: The word "right" in that context simply meant "correct". :-)

Comment: Haha, well that was simpler than I was making it. In my defense, linear algebra isn't commutative so it was an understandable mistake, I hope.

Comment: I also got something wrote up, I'm going to post it as an answer. Would you mind commenting on it if you think it's incorrect?

Comment: @user115656: I can try.

Answer (score 0):

$\Leftarrow$ Assume dim$(V/W)<\infty$ and dim$(V/U)<\infty$. We know then dim$(V/W \oplus V/U) = (\text{dim}(V/W)\cdot \text{dim}(V/U))<\infty$. We know there is an injective function from $V/(W\cap U) \xrightarrow{\phi} V/U\oplus V/W$, and if dim$(V/(W\cap U))\not < \infty$ then there could not exist an injective linear transformation between $V/(W\cap U)$ and $V/U \oplus V/W$. So then dim$(V/(W\cap U))<\infty$.

(The existence of that injective transformation was given in an earlier problem about short exact sequences.)